# Python Regex to detect underscore between letters

Tags: python, regex

How do I make a regex in python that returns a string with all underscores between lowercase letters?
For example, it should detect and return: `'aa_bb_cc' ,  'swd_qq' , 'hello_there_friend'`

But it should not return these: `'aA_bb' , 'aa_'  ,  '_ddQ' , 'aa_baa_2cs'`

My code is `([a-z]+_[a-z]+)+`    ,  but it returns only one underscore. It should return all underscores seperated by lowercase letters.

For example, when I pass the string `"aab_cbbbc_vv"`, it returns only `'aab_cbbbc'` instead of `'aab_cbbbc_vv'`

Thank you

Comment: the problem is because you also "asks" for upper case letter. switch `[a-zA-Z]` to `[a-z]`

Comment: Ive changed the code but it still return only one underscore

Comment: @cxs101 May be `[a-z_]+`

Comment: can you write the whole code, cuz im not sure what you mean

Comment: @cxs101: could you please consider accepting one of the answers (grey tick mark besides the answer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct. If you change it to:

```
^([a-z]+)(_[a-z]+)+$
```

It woks as you can check [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(%5Ba-z%5D%2B)(_%5Ba-z%5D%2B)%2B%24&test_string=aa_bb_cc%0Aswd_qq%0Ahello_there_friend&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=1).

`^` - matches the beginning of the string

`$` - the end of the string

You need these so that you are not getting partial matches when matching the strings you don't want to get matched.

Answer (score 1):

try this code to get it

```
import re
s = "aa_bb_cc swd_qq hello_there_friend aA_bb aa_ _ddQ aa_baa_2cs"
print(re.findall(r"[a-z][a-z_]+\_[a-z]+",s))
```

the output sould be

```
['aa_bb_cc', 'swd_qq', 'hello_there_friend', 'aa_baa']
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get only results with 1 underscore for your example data is that `([a-z]+_[a-z]+)+` repeats a match of [a-z]+, then an underscore and then again [a-z]+

That would for example match `a_b` or `a_bc_d`, but only a partial match for `a_b_c` as there has to be at least a char a-z present before each _ for every iteration.

You could update your pattern to:

```
\b[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `[a-z]+` Match 1+ chars a-z
- `(?:_[a-z]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `_` and 1+ chars a-z
- `\b` A word boundary

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvXSty/1)